# c# equivalent of \x php escape sequence?

Tags: c#, php, escaping

Is there any equivalent of \x PHP  escape sequence in c# ?
see my examples:

```
<?php  
$a = "\xC1";  
$b = "\x82";  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may have been previously answered, check this previous post out to see if it helps:

[C# Build hexadecimal notation string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284093/c-sharp-build-hexadecimal-notation-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, sort of, with \u. This will insert a *unicode* character in to the string. Strings in .Net are unicode, so you can't throw in single byte values like you can in other languages.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx .