# How to convert this VB code to c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets

I have VB code which I'm converting to C#. I've created a large chunk of the program but I'm stuck at one line of this fuction:

```
Private Sub Arduino_Write(ByVal Output As String)
    If Not IsNothing(networkStream) Then
        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Output)
        Dim endByte As [Byte]() = {&HFE}
        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
        networkStream.Write(endByte, 0, 1)
    Else
        MsgBox("ERROR")
    End If
End Sub
```

What I know is endByte is a Byte type array and I don't know what &HFE is and how to convert or typecast it in C#.
Can anybody please help me?

Comment: There are some online converters - Google will help you ;-) Or you can use convert.net.

Comment: Just try to google: **Online c# to vb.net**

Comment: `&HFE` is a hex literal. In C# it translates to `0xFE`

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284093/c-sharp-build-hexadecimal-notation-string) tell you everything you need to know and can be found with simple Google searches.

Comment: @Waseem Tahir have you try my answer ? if it is help for u please accept it :) good luck

Answer (score 1):

`&HFE` just means the hexadecimal for 254. In C# this would be:

```
byte[] endByte = { 0xFE };
```

Comment: Thanks, it was great help.

Answer (score 1):

It's an array with a single value of hex FE.  in C# you can write this as:

```
byte[] endByte = {0xFE};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
private void Arduino_Write(string Output)
{
    if (networkStream != null) {
        var sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Output);
        var endByte = { 0xfe };
        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
        networkStream.Write(endByte, 0, 1);
    } else {
        Interaction.MsgBox("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, it was the exact thing I was searching for.

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to vote up and accept and I'll love you forever :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try some online converters, they are okay. Google will find many. ;)

Here an example from http://converter.telerik.com/

```
private void Arduino_Write(string Output)
{
    if ((networkStream != null)) {
        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Output);
        Byte[] endByte = { 0xfe };
        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
        networkStream.Write(endByte, 0, 1);
    } else {
        Interaction.MsgBox("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

you can compile the VB code and use the dissasembler in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to see C# code. Some of the variable names will change.

```
private void Arduino_Write(string Output)
{
    if ((networkStream != null)) {
        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Output);
        Byte[] endByte = { 0xfe };
        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
        networkStream.Write(endByte, 0, 1);
    } else {
        Interaction.MsgBox("ERROR");
    }
}
```

in the internet have more online converters.here are some converters

http://converter.telerik.com/

http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

Sometimes the **conversion is not 100% accurate**, but it is definitely very helpful.you also can use Visual Studio 2012 plug-in named [Language Convert](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LuPaLaPaoloSalamone.LanguageConvert) (works perfectly with 2010/2012)